# const vs Func<string>

Tags: c#

Any advantage or difference in using const or Func in a class ?

```
public sealed class Constants {
  private Constants() {}
  public const string SOME_STRING = "Some String";
  public static Func<string> SomeString = () => "Some String";
}


Debug.WriteLine(Constants.SOME_STRING);
Debug.WriteLine(Constants.SomeString());
```

Comment: I never even thought about using `Func` as a `const` replacement. I thought using r/o properties would be a valid replacement.

Comment: Don't forget about `readonly` values.

Comment: If you want something close to a const, but with the benefits of being able to change it later, use a `public static readonly` instead of a Func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you've shown, use a `const`. Your intent is clear that way.

A `Func` is just a function, represented as an object. You don't seem to *need* a function, so why use one? A direct access is simpler to understand and more people will expect it. If I saw that usage of a Func, I would definitely do a double take.

Comment: Think the const is the most obvious in terms of intent the other way feels to me like doing dentistry through your ass.

Answer (score 4):

At compile time, Constants.SOME_STRING will be replaced by its actual value of 'Some String' and the compilation will continue as if literals were used.

Calls to SomeString() will still result in a stack call to the static method.

Comment: Aren't chances very high that it would get inlined?

Answer (score 3):

The constant doesn't need to be evaluated, and so will give you a slight performance gain. If you're sure this string won't ever need to change, use a constant.

If you think the value may need to be produced by some logic at some point in the future, or it may change from one product version to the next, try using a property instead. It gives you the same amount of flexibility as a `Func<>` would, but allows you to use syntax syntax that doesn't imply the possibility of having some other effect.

```
public string SomeString {get {return "Some String";}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Constant are subsituted by their values where they are referred in code so they are faster. Making a Func and calling it in code will increase function call and decrease performance